# FreeBSD MacOS Grep Spanning Multiple Lines

Tags: macos, terminal, grep

Using MacOS High Sierra, trying to using grep to extract the text between two "tags." Intended output should be "The Genre". Here's the .txt file:

```
<genre>
The Genre
</genre>
```

Here's the grep command that's not working:

```
genre=$(grep -o '(?<=<genre>).*?(=<\/genre>)' textfile.txt)
```

echo $genre

I am approaching this the wrong way for MacOS? All the commands I've seen with tags only support BNU or Linux variants. Help appreciated

Comment: If you use a PCRE regex use `grep` with `-P` option, or use `pcregrep`

Comment: (Being line-based) `grep` is not the tool for it. This is a good start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-print-lines-between-two-patterns-inclusive-or-exclusive-in-sed-awk-or

Comment: Can't use -P option with MacOS / BSD grep command.

Answer (score 0):

For multiline search you can use MacOS/FreeBSD **pcregrep** utility. It is installed with **pcre** package

```
pcregrep -o -M '(?s)(?<=<genre>).*(?=<\/genre>)' textfile.txt
```

Command explanation:

`-o` - show matched string

`-M` - use multiline search

`(?s)` - make "." to match any character whatsoever, even a newline

`(?<=<genre>)` - match prefix **<genre>** but not show it in output

`(?=<\/genre>)` - match postfix **</genre>** but not show it in output

**Important note**:
This command will match everything between opening and closing tags including newlines. So output will be this:

```
The Genre
```